# Unity animation plays in preview but not in playing mode

Tags: unity, animation, animation-controller, animator

I create a simple animation and an override controller for it with code.

```
//AnimationScript.cs
public Vector3 direction;
public float distance;

void Start()
{
    direction = direction.normalized;
    Vector3 posA = transform.position;
    Vector3 posB = posA + (direction * distance);

    AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip();
    AnimationCurve curve = AnimationCurve.Linear(0.0f, posA.y, 1.0f, posB.y);
    clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.y", curve);

    Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    AnimatorOverrideController animatorOverrideController = new AnimatorOverrideController(anim.runtimeAnimatorController);
    // "loop" is the name of clip not name of state
    animatorOverrideController["loop"] = clip;
    anim.runtimeAnimatorController = animatorOverrideController;
}
```

When I preview animation it works perfect, but when I export and play it, it does not start but camera motion works. What is the reason for that and how do I correct it?

Here are my object settings and controller:

[image: object settings]

[image: base animation controller]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SetCurve API Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.SetCurve.html) has this to say:

> `SetCurve` will only work at runtime for legacy animation clips. For non-legacy AnimationClips it is an editor-only function.

I’m guessing that this is the problem, since you are working with an Animator.

Comment: You are right. Animation works with 'Animation' component. But when i run it i get exception: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.GetAnimationModeDriver () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:474).